# What's the cause of a D8049 error in visual studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2015, openframeworks

I'm creating a project with openframeworks (the full source is here: https://github.com/morphogencc/ofxAsio/tree/master/example-udpreceiver), and the empty project seems to compile fine.

I added the ASIO library, and a few header classes, and now the project seems to be give me the following error:

`1>------ Build started: Project: example-udpreceiver, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>  main.cpp
1>cl : Command line error D8049: cannot execute 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\c1xx.dll': command line is too long to fit in debug record
1>cl : Command line error D8040: error creating or communicating with child process`

I couldn't find any examples of error D8049 on stackoverflow or even on Microsoft's pages, and google turned up painfully few results.  The only remotely useful one was this github issue:

https://github.com/deplinenoise/tundra/issues/270

But I'm still not sure what's causing the problem.  Is anyone familiar with this error, and can recommend a method for troubleshooting what's causing it?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit of a weird sounding error, as it is from essentially internally generated data.  However, you do have control over that.  Taking the error message at face value, you probably have many/lots of defined symbols passed in on the command line (or the the ones you do have have lengthy definitions), or you may have some lengthy file paths.

If you look under the project properties, one of the selections under the C++ section is "Command Line", which will show you exactly what gets passed to the compiler.  When you view that you can see where you have many or lengthy parameters, and then make changes to shorten them.

Too many defines?  Put them in a header (possibly stdafx.h) and include them that way.

Long file paths?  Shorten the paths, put the files somewhere else, or set up file system aliases to your real directories that use shorter paths.

Comment: Thanks; looking at the command line arguments helped me sort out what had been added that shouldn't have been!  There were waaaay too many irrelevant files included as additional include directories.

Answer (score 5):

For me, working with UE4, this was an intermittent error.

I added "bLegacyPublicIncludePaths = false;" to the innermost block of project.Build.cs and recompiled without errors.

Then I removed that line and compiled again w/o errors.

The error message suggested adding "DefaultBuildSettings = BuildSettingsVersion.V2;" to project.Target.cs which worked.